# Getting CLBeacon's information from AppDelegate to View Controller in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, viewcontroller, appdelegate

I'm new to swift and have gone around and around trying to figure it out.  I know I have it over complicated if I had to guess but need some help.

I'm trying to use iBeacon to read the UUID, Major and Minor values off of a beacon then use that to drive an image in the view controller.

In the AppDelegate.swift file I am able to get the information and use println to get it out.  The AppDelegate file is the following:

---

```
    import UIKit
    import CoreLocation

    @UIApplicationMain

    class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager?
    var lastProximity: CLProximity?
    var lastUUID: NSUUID!
    var lastBeacanIdentifier:String = ""
    var lastMajorValue: NSNumber = 0.0
    var lastMinorValue: NSNumber = 0.0

    func application(application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {

            let uuidString = "99C2E498-7606-4575-A353-5F710834E75B"
            let beaconIdentifier = "co.Company"
            let beaconUUID:NSUUID = NSUUID(UUIDString: uuidString)
            let beaconRegion:CLBeaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: beaconUUID, identifier: beaconIdentifier)

            locationManager = CLLocationManager()
            if(locationManager!.respondsToSelector("requestAlwaysAuthorization")) {
                locationManager!.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            }

            locationManager!.delegate = self
            locationManager!.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false

            locationManager!.startMonitoringForRegion(beaconRegion)
            locationManager!.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(beaconRegion)
            locationManager!.startUpdatingLocation()

            if(application.respondsToSelector("registerUserNotificationSettings:")) {
                application.registerUserNotificationSettings(
                    UIUserNotificationSettings(
                        forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Sound,
                        categories: nil
                    )
                )
            }
            return true
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }


}

extension AppDelegate: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func sendLocalNotificationWithMessage(message: String!) {
        let notification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
        notification.alertBody = message
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!,
        didRangeBeacons beacons: [AnyObject]!,
        inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion!) {
            NSLog("didRangeBeacons");
            var message:String = ""

            if(beacons.count > 0) {
                let nearestBeacon:CLBeacon = beacons[0] as CLBeacon

                if(nearestBeacon.proximity == lastProximity ||
                    nearestBeacon.proximity == CLProximity.Unknown) {
                        return;
                }

                lastProximity = nearestBeacon.proximity;
                lastMajorValue = nearestBeacon.major;
                lastMinorValue = nearestBeacon.minor;
                lastUUID = nearestBeacon.proximityUUID;


                switch nearestBeacon.proximity {
                case CLProximity.Far:
                    message = "You are far away from the beacon";
                    println(lastMajorValue)
                    println(lastMinorValue)
                    println(lastUUID)
                case CLProximity.Near:
                    message = "You are near the beacon";
                    println(lastMajorValue)
                    println(lastMinorValue)
                    println(lastUUID)
                case CLProximity.Immediate:
                    message = "You are in the immediate proximity of the beacon";
                    println(lastMajorValue)
                    println(lastMinorValue)
                    println(lastUUID)
                case CLProximity.Unknown:
                    return
                }
            } else {
                message = "No beacons are nearby"
            }

            NSLog("%@", message)
            sendLocalNotificationWithMessage(message)
    }
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!,
        didEnterRegion region: CLRegion!) {
            manager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region as CLBeaconRegion)
            manager.startUpdatingLocation()

            NSLog("You entered the region")
            sendLocalNotificationWithMessage("You entered the region")
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!,
        didExitRegion region: CLRegion!) {
            manager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(region as CLBeaconRegion)
            manager.stopUpdatingLocation()

            NSLog("You exited the region")
            sendLocalNotificationWithMessage("You exited the region")
    }
}
```

---

The View Controller file is the following:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController{


    @IBOutlet weak var advertismentImageArea: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func closeAdvertisementButton(sender: UIButton) {
        advertismentImageArea.hidden = true
    }
    var beaconInformation: AppDelegate!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var closestBeacon = beaconInformation


        var majorNumber = closestBeacon.lastMajorValue


        if  majorNumber  == 6303 {
            advertismentImageArea.image = UIImage(named: "AdOne")
        } else if majorNumber == 21456 {
            advertismentImageArea.image = UIImage(named: "AdTwo")
        } else {
            return advertismentImageArea.hidden = true;
        }
    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



}
```

I would really appreciate any help you all can provide.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to use the iOS Delegation pattern.  It's not the only way to solve this problem.

What you would do would be to create a Protocol in your AppDelegate class

```
@protocol BeaconLocationDelegate
{
   func majorBeaconChanged(majorValue:NSNumber)
}
```

You would then also add the following variable to your AppDelegate class

```
weak var locationDelegate: BeaconLocationDelegate?
```

Inside your ViewController class you would then declare that your class implements the BeaconLocationDelegate protocol

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, BeaconLocationDelegate
```

and then somewhere in viewDidload add the following line of code

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.locationDelegate = self
```

and then implement the protocol method to update the UI however you want for your app

```
   func majorBeaconChanged(majorValue:NSNumber)
```

And lastly, inside your AppDelegate class whenever you detect the change in the beacon you would then invoke code like:

```
locationDelegate?.majorBeaconChanged(newMajorValue)
```